# Hosting website in INTRAnet environment

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there any safe way to host a site Net core website through a installer (may be in IIS), similar to any desktop application installer?

e.g. Neo4j works as webservice but  has its own jetty server to host. U just download and its up and working.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand your problem. Why you just dont run your app with Kestrel? (`dotnet <patch_to_your_dll`)

Comment: u mean like executable ?

Comment: It will just run your app in .Net CLI. App will take port (Kestrel most directly) and have silmplest ever running Asp.Net Core App

Comment: I mentioned IIS or any other server (irrespective of OS) just because the reason cause it take cares of keeping it healthy. It wont stop.
REASON : Requirement is I want to give it to some client (Which I hope will increase in future). It will run as their in-house app. So I want to automate this process reliably